# Generar archivo de firma digital CMS añadiendo PKCS#1 externo con Java

Tags: java, firma-digital

Estoy generando archivos de firma CMS añadiendo el PKCS#1 generado en otra aplicación basandome en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470156/adding-external-pkcs1-byte-array-and-certificate-to-cms-container-with-java).

Primero obtengo los atributos a firmar del archivo original que serán firmados en la aplicación externa la cual me regresa un arreglo de bytes con el PKCS#1.

Después construyo un objeto estandar org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInfoGenerator con el hash original del archivo, el PKCS#1 y el certificado para añadir en la estructura CMS, y finalmente creo la **firma CMS con los datos adjuntos.**

Pero cuando trato de validar el archivo usando este código:

```
    String originalFile = "aG9sYQ0KYXNkYXMNCg0KYWZzDQo=";
    String cmsSignedFile = "MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExDzANBg...j2Dwytp6kzQNwtXGO8QbWty1lOo8oYm+6LR8EWba3ikO/m9ol/G808vit9gAAAAAAAA==";
    byte[] signedByte = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(cmsSignedFile);

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    CMSSignedData s = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableByteArray(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(originalFile)), signedByte);
    SignerInformationStore signers = s.getSignerInfos();
    SignerInformation signerInfo = (SignerInformation)signers.getSigners().iterator().next();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/myCertificate.cer");
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificates(fis).iterator().next();

    boolean result = signerInfo.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert.getPublicKey())); 
    System.out.println("Verified: "+result);
```

Obtengo falso en la verificación.

Estoy añadiendo Content Type, Signing time, Message digest y la respuesta OCSP como atributos a firmar y el token TSP como atributos sin firmar (no estoy seguro si esto es correcto).

También necesito recuperar los datos de la firma CMS generada, estoy usando este código:

```
//cargar archivo de firma CMS
    CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("C:/tmp/tempFile1864328163858309463.cms")));

    System.out.println(cms.getSignerInfos().getSigners().iterator().next().getDigestAlgorithmID().getAlgorithm().getId());
    System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(cms.getSignerInfos().getSigners().iterator().next().getSignature()));

    //recuperar informacion del certificado
    Store certs = cms.getCertificates();
    Collection<X509CertificateHolder> col = certs.getMatches(null);
    X509CertificateHolder []h1 = col.toArray(new X509CertificateHolder[col.size()]);
    X509CertificateHolder firmante = h1[0];
    System.out.println(firmante.getSubject());
    System.out.println(h1[1].getSubject());
    SignerInformation sinfo = cms.getSignerInfos().getSigners().iterator().next();

    //recuperar informacin de OCSP
    //ESTO NO FUNCIONA :(
//          Store infocspbasic = cms.getOtherRevocationInfo(OCSPObjectIdentifiers.id_pkix_ocsp_basic);
//          Object basic = infocspbasic.getMatches(null).iterator().next();


    //recuperar hora de firmado
    if (sinfo.getSignedAttributes() != null) {

        Attribute timeStampAttr = sinfo.getSignedAttributes().get(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_signingTime);
        ASN1Encodable attrValue = timeStampAttr.getAttrValues().getObjectAt(0);

        final Date signingDate;
        if (attrValue instanceof ASN1UTCTime) {
            ASN1UTCTime time =  ASN1UTCTime.getInstance(attrValue);
            Date d = time.getDate();
            System.out.println("ASN1UTCTime:" + d);
        } else if (attrValue instanceof Time) {
            signingDate = ((Time) attrValue).getDate();
        } else if (attrValue instanceof ASN1GeneralizedTime) {
            System.out.println("ASN1GeneralizedTimeASN1GeneralizedTime");
        } else {
            signingDate = null;
        }
    }


    //recuperar token TSP
    //los atributos no firmados llegan nulos :(
    if (sinfo.getUnsignedAttributes() != null) {

        Attribute timeStampAttr = sinfo.getUnsignedAttributes().get(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken);

        for (ASN1Encodable value : timeStampAttr.getAttrValues().toArray()) {
            TimeStampToken token = new TimeStampToken(new CMSSignedData(value.toASN1Primitive().getEncoded()));
            System.out.println(token.getTimeStampInfo().getGenTime());
        }

    }
```

Pero no puedo recuperar la respuesta OCSP ni la información del token TSP.

Adicionalmente descargué [este visor de archivos CMS](https://www.signfiles.com/p7s-viewer/) para ayudarme a verificar, el resultado es este:

[image: Resultado visor CMS]

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré un proyecto llamado [j4sign](https://sourceforge.net/p/j4sign/discussion/432583/thread/22748439/) el cual implementa firma CMS con PKCS#1 externo. El enlace lleva al foro del proyecto con el código ejemplo que utilicé implementando sus clases y la corrección final para que funcionará correctamente la validación.